# Android GeoFence Not Starting

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, android-geofence

Note **please read my full question before down voting**

So I've followed the documentation I found here [link here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-geofences-on-android--cms-26639)

This is my manifest code

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Service class code**

```
  private void startGeofence(float lat, float lon, float radius) {
        Log.i("INFO", "startGeofence() in Gps Service");
        System.out.println("startGeofence in GPS Service"+lat+"\t"+lon+"\t"+radius);
        Geofence geofence = createGeofence( lat,lon, radius);
        GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest( geofence );
        addGeofence( geofenceRequest );
    }

    // Create a Geofence
    private Geofence createGeofence(float lat, float lon, float radius) {
        Log.d("INFO", "createGeofence");
        int delay;
        int time=pref.getInt("time",300000);
       if (this.radius!=0){this.radius=300;}
        System.out.println("Fence Service Co-ordinates in Gps Service are :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: "+lat+" , "+lon+":"+ this.radius);
        System.out.println("Time arrived for loitering delay in Gps Service are  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: "+time);
        if (time<=0)
            delay=300000;
        else
        delay=time;
        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_REQ_ID)
                .setCircularRegion(lat,lon,radius)
                .setExpirationDuration(GEO_DURATION)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                        | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build();
    }


    // Create a Geofence Request
    private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest(Geofence geofence) {
        Log.d("INFO", "createGeofenceRequest"); System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Request Created ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
                .addGeofence(geofence)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        addNotification("Low memory.. removing service");
        if (!googleApiClient.isConnecting() || !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            googleApiClient.connect();
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(this.googleApiClient, this);
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(this.googleApiClient, createGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
        stopSelf();
    }

    private PendingIntent geoFencePendingIntent;

    private final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;
    private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Log.d("INFO", "createGeofencePendingIntent");
        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: createGeofencePendingIntent ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        if (geoFencePendingIntent != null)
            return geoFencePendingIntent;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTrasitionService.class);
//        return PendingIntent.getService(
//                this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent =   PendingIntent.getService(this,GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        if (pendingIntent == null){
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::::: Service not called:::::::::::::::::::::::");
        } else {
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::::: Service is Alrady Called:::::::::::::::::::::::");
        }
        return pendingIntent;


    }

    // Add the created GeofenceRequest to the device's monitoring list
    private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
        Log.d("INFO", "addGeofence");
        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: addGeofence::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                googleApiClient,
                request,
                createGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
        Log.i("INFO", "onResult: " + status);
        if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
            System.out.println("Status Success in Fence Service");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Status failed in Fence Service");
        }
    }


    private void addNotification(String message) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location)
                        .setContentTitle("GeoFence Status")
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setContentText(message);

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigText.bigText(message);
        builder.setStyle(bigText);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        // Add as notification
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(++notif, builder.build());
    }

    public void showNotification(String text, String bigText) {

        // 1. Create a NotificationManager
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // 2. Create a PendingIntent for AllGeofencesActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // 3. Create and send a notification
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location)
                .setContentTitle(text)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(bigText))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

}
```

**GeoFenceTranstionservice.class**

```
package com.example.vishal.geofencing;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofenceStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class GeofenceTrasitionService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = GeofenceTrasitionService.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final int GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

    public GeofenceTrasitionService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        // Handling errors
        if ( geofencingEvent.hasError() ) {
            String errorMsg = getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode() );
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Error in GeoFence Transition::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"+errorMsg);
            Log.e( TAG, errorMsg );
            return;
        }

        int geoFenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::::::::::Started Transition:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"+geoFenceTransition);
        // Check if the transition type is of interest
        if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT || geoFenceTransition==Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) {
            // Get the geofence that were triggered
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(geoFenceTransition, triggeringGeofences );

            // Send notification details as a String
            sendNotification( geofenceTransitionDetails );
        }else {
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Invalid GeoFence Transition::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        }
    }


    private String getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(int geoFenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
        // get the ID of each geofence triggered
        ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences ) {
            triggeringGeofencesList.add( geofence.getRequestId() );
        }

        String status = null;
        if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER )
            status = "Entering ";

        else if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
            status = "Exiting ";
        else if (geoFenceTransition==Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL)
            status="dwelling";
        System.out.println("Status Of Geo Fence Transiiton is:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"+status);
        showNotification("GeoFence Status",status);

        return status + TextUtils.join( ", ", triggeringGeofencesList);
    }

    private void sendNotification( String msg ) {
        Log.i(TAG, "sendNotification: " + msg );

        // Intent to start the main Activity
        Intent notificationIntent = MainActivity.makeNotificationIntent(
                getApplicationContext(), msg
        );

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        // Creating and sending Notification
        NotificationManager notificatioMng =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        notificatioMng.notify(
                GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                createNotification(msg, notificationPendingIntent));

    }

    // Create notification
    private Notification createNotification(String msg, PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setContentText("Geofence Notification!")
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        return notificationBuilder.build();
    }


    private static String getErrorString(int errorCode) {
        switch (errorCode) {
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                return "GeoFence not available";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
                return "Too many GeoFences";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
                return "Too many pending intents";
            default:
                return "Unknown error.";
        }
    }

    public void showNotification(String text, String bigText) {

        // 1. Create a NotificationManager
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // 2. Create a PendingIntent for AllGeofencesActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // 3. Create and send a notification
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location)
                .setContentTitle(text)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(bigText))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

After implementing Geo Fencing in application, the geo Fence intent is also getting called. (the radius of the geo fence is acquired when the user adds 2 marker points, where the first says the center of circle fence and second marker determines radius) but the Geo Fence Service is not activating.
ie,
Geofence isn't triggering the PendingIntent even though its been added successfully.

service declared in Androidmanifest.

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".GeofenceTrasitionService"/>
```

Comment: How are you testing, emulator or device? Are you approaching your fence with the mock data or just jumping in?

Comment: real device is used and no mock locations are provided

Comment: Recommend trying a mock location provider where you start outside your fence and enter at a walking or driving pace. In my experience the fence wouldn't trigger immediately, but after a few minutes to let the location settle.

Comment: How big is your geofence (radius) and how far from the center are you moving to?

Comment: well the fence radius is dynamic.. given by two markers